# How to make 3 different voltages in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-design

I have 1 circuit composed from 3 little very simple circuits
I want to power them all from a 5V@1A power source.
All of these 3 circuits must be powered at different voltages.
Their current draw I measured for each of them.

A=4V @10mA, B=3.4V @1.6mA, C= 5V @24mA

What can you suggest?

Thank you.

(I re-edited)

Comment: If they all take identical currents you can put them in series and feed the composite from 12 volts.

Comment: You’re kidding, right?

Comment: So, you want to supply circuit A, B and C using the same 5V power supply? Please hit the edit link and also state the required currents.

Comment: @teodoric8. - Welcome :-) (a) Just FYI your comment above to *Huisman* didn't notify them, as there was a space between the `@` and the username. To work correctly, the username (with no spaces, if multiple words) must immediately follow the `@`. On a desktop browser, you will be offered a choice of usernames after typing `@` and the first letter. (b) Are you really sure that you need those specific voltages? They are  unusual and might point to an X-Y problem, but without a schematic and more details, we can't validate for you. Please add a schematic, if you want readers to check. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson - thank you for the help with the text syntax. I will be more careful from now on. About my question, its just a very general and simple problem. Not a tricky one. So general, from top of your head answers should do. Thank you for taking care. :)

Comment: @Huisman - i added the required currents.

Comment: For 10mA and 1.6mA, Zeners are an option.

Answer (score 5):

For the 5V, connect directly.

For 3V and 4V, a linear LDO regulator for each one. Assuming they’re low current, linear would be fine.

The LDO (low drop-out) part is important. The regulator 'overhead' (or drop-out) voltage, needs to be less than the required Vin - Vout, with your worst case (lowest) Vin.

---

**Why LDOs?**

tl; dr version: the required overhead (drop-out) between Vin (5V) and the two Vout (4V, 3V) is too low to be satisfied by a non-LDO regulator like an LM317.

**Analysis**

Assuming +/-10% on your 5V supply, your lowest Vin will be 4.5V. Then, the maximum overhead allowed for each of your supplies is:

- 4V supply: 4.5V - 4V = **0.5V**
- 3V (3.3?) supply: 4.5V - 3V = **1.5V**

Neither of these can be satisfied by a non LDO regulator like the LM317, which has an overhead (drop-out) voltage of **3V**. That won't work for this setup.

So you need LDOs. These have overhead (drop-out) of about **150 - 200mV**, lower than your required overhead. More about those here: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/understand-ldo-concepts.html